# "An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again"

Tags: bug

Recently I see the following message quite often:

> An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again

I’m not sure why this happens, the problem however is that I cannot *try again* because the buttons disappear. Please fix this. Reloading the page every time this happens is very annoying.

[image]